# Flutter Mobx Observer doesnt rebuild

Tags: flutter, mobx

I have no Idea anymore.

I am using Mobx for really simple State Management.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';
import 'package:jw_helper/state/globalState.dart';

class Router extends StatelessWidget {
  const Router({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _globalState = GlobalState();
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Observer(
            builder: (_) => Text(_globalState?.currentIndex?.toString()),
          ),
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _globalState.setCurrentIndex(1);
          },
          child: Text("Press me"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When i mutate the state in this widget the value updates. 
When i mutate the same Observable in another Widget the Observer is not rebuilding.

Only the observer in the same Widget where the State is mutated is updated.

My Mobx Code:

```
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';

// Include generated file
part 'globalState.g.dart';

// This is the class used by rest of your codebase
class GlobalState = _GlobalState with _$GlobalState;

// The store-class
abstract class _GlobalState with Store {
  @observable
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @action
  void setCurrentIndex(index) {
    currentIndex = index;
    print(currentIndex);
  }
}
```

Small note: The Print Statement is always fired

Maybe someone knows how to fix this.
Thank you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Problem was solved with Help from a Discord Mobx Channel Member.

The solution was to wrap the whole App in a provider Widget.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
------------------------------------------------
    return Provider<GlobalState>(
      create: (context) => GlobalState(),
------------------------------------------------
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the Widgets consuming the Mobx Class i did:

```
class Router extends StatelessWidget {
  const Router({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _globalState = Provider.of<GlobalState>(context);
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(.....
```

Hopefully this helps somebody to get up and running ;)

Comment: Does this mean every single state in my app has to be a part of the GlobalState?

Comment: @LêQuangBảo You could use MultiProvider as explained [here](https://mobx.netlify.com/guides/stores#using-providers-to-avoid-singletons)

Answer (score 0):

Not a finished (nor will be) app but hopefully can help as a start.

Flutter + Mobx + (Multi) Providers

https://github.com/jonataswalker/flutter-example

Answer (score 0):

You have two instances of GlobalState class. One for each widget. In order for Observer works correctly it needs to observe always the same instance.

Using "Provider" you are kind of using the Singleton pattern which solves the problem since both variables start refering to the same instance

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem

Always rebuild mobX after any changes u place inside main store file

flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs